# How to count number sums on iterating rows in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, variables

Information of marks is taken from an Excel sheet. The range of exam marks differs in each sheet, so there would is no fixed number of rows or columns. This code snippet can add all the exam marks (with their weights) to one variable, however it is hardcoded. I would like, but don't know what variable I should use, to make the summing-up softcoded.

```
i, u, total_mark = 0, 0, []
sheet = wb.active                   
for row in sheet.iter_cols(max_row=99, max_col=29, values_only=True):  
    for cell in row:
        u += 1
        for i in range(1, 100): 
            cell_bc = sheet.cell(row=i, column=u)
            if cell_bc.value is None:
                continue
            else:
                if check(cell_bc.value) != "Invalid":
                    y = int(check(cell_bc.value)[:-1])
                    for ii in range(1, 97):
                        sheet.iter_rows()
                        cell_student_marks = sheet.cell(row=i+ii, column=u)
                        **roww = 5**
                        if type(cell_student_marks.value) == int and cell_student_marks.value >= 30:
                            part_mark = (cell_student_marks.value * y) / 100
                            print(4, cell_student_marks.value, ", part-mark:",
                                  part_mark, ", coordinates:", cell_student_marks.coordinate)

                            **if cell_student_marks.row == roww:**
                                total_mark.append(part_mark)
                                print(5, sum(total_mark))
```

I tried (and it worked as wanted) to set just one row (roww = 5 in the example), it gave me back only the 5th row's sumed-up mark, however I would like to get every row's sumed-up marks seperately (i. e. have every student's marks assigned to only to them and not a one "blob" of all the exam results) not depending on the number of rows (and then see if a student passed).

Comment: You don't seem to have much data (less than 100 rows), so what I suggest doing is converting the excel data to a csv, then to a pandas dataframe, and try to work with that using iterrows. It is one the slowest methods of using pandas data row by row, but with only 100 rows the difference is negligible and I personally think it is one of the easiest row iterators to understand.